# Bulk data insertion using SQL loader

Tags: java, informatica, sql-loader

i am trying to dump 60 million records in to oracle database using sql loader. but it is taking more than 50 mins with options(direct=true,rows = 100000).

Do we have any option to make data insertion bit faster. Can we use informatica or java to dump data to make it faster. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify parallel option

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_modes.htm#i1008225

You also can see [Loading large amounts of data to an Oracle SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992456/loading-large-amounts-of-data-to-an-oracle-sql-database)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Oracle specific jdbc (Java) extension [Oracle Update Batching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#sthref744). It's the fastest way I've seen to get data from a simple program into any database. Just set the batch size to at least 10,000. You play with the max size until you find something that works for you.

Since this is just plain Java SE you can of course run this in parallel across many threads.

If you're going from one Oracle database to another, check out [dmp files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm). Simply dump from one and then import into another.